# Turn By Turn Navigation in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit, ios7

I am working on a navigation app to show turn by turn driving directions. In iOS 6 we have to pass data to ios map app, but i want to show it without leaving the app.

Apple has introduced new directions API in iOS 7, so now in iOS 7 is it possible to show Turn By Turn Navigation within the app(in MKMapView) ?

Comment: Did you found any solutions for this ? I am also having the same requirement.

Comment: Did you find any solution? @virat naithani

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 7, you can use something like this to render driving direction within your app:

```
MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
[request setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];
[request setDestination:myMapItem];
[request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAny];
[request setRequestsAlternateRoutes:YES];
MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (MKRoute *route in [response routes]) {
            [myMapView addOverlay:[route polyline] level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Can i put this code into 
- (MKOverlayView )mapView:(MKMapView )mapView viewForOverlay:
or any other method. and what is myMapItem?

Answer (score 0):

this page can be helpful for you if you want to render paths between two locations.
As an alternative you can also use Googles directions API which is accepted by apple.

http://iosguy.com/tag/directions-api/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: Thanks Buddy but i know how to plot path between 2 points. But i want Turn By Turn Navigation like iOS6 Map App.

Comment: @ViratNaithani have you found any solution for turn by turn navigation for iOS using google map sdk?